Feature to list and search through list of components in Angular does not work correctly on production
I have the following function that basically collects the list of component children from my parent component and enables search functionality for them (shows the name of component in html list and on clicking it directs to route of that component). The issue I face is that the name property of each component comes up correctly on dev environment but on the production it always shows up as "t". What am I doing wrong here?
 search() {
const homeComponentConfig = this.router.config.find(
  (x) => x.component == HomeComponent
);

if (homeComponentConfig && homeComponentConfig.children) {
  this.searchedPages = homeComponentConfig.children
    .filter(
      (x) =>
        x.component &&
        x.component.name &&
        x.component.name
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.searchTerm?.toLowerCase().trim())
    )
    .map((item) => {
      return {
        name: item.component.name
          .replace("Component", "")
          .split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
          .join(" "),
        path: item.path,
      };
    });
}

}
    <ng-container *ngIf="searchedPages?.length">
                <ul [ngStyle]="{ 'list-style': 'none' }">
                  <li
                    class="search-list"
                    *ngFor="let item of searchedPages; let i = index"
                    (click)="navigateToPage(item?.path)"
                  >
                    {{ item?.name }}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </ng-container>


component classes are minified in production, that is expected. you can turn the build optimization or mangling off, but that would increase the bundle size

if that is the case, why does the routing part still work when I click on one of the list items?

item.path is a sting with some value set in your application. class references get mangled into short class references
